# Algorithm to find a point perpendicular to two other points

Tags: math, vector, geometry, computational-geometry

I am trying to write an algorithm to  solve this problem:

[image]

P1, P2 and P3 are given. I am looking for P4 and h.

The line between P3 and P4 should be parallel to the line between P1 and P2.

P4 should be perpendicular to the line between P1 and P2 at P2.

P1, P2 and P3 can be anywhere on the plane.

Comment: Is `h` the distance between `P2` and `P4`? Just how are the points given: in Cartesian coordinates? What kind of algorithm do you want: compass and straightedge, calculations on coordinates, or other? What work have you done on this problem and just where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes sorry, messed up with the terms perpendicular and parallel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a geometric problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance `h` can get calculated as shown in [the wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line)

For the coordinates of P4, first let's get the equation on line P1P2:

```
y-y1    x-x1 
----- = -----   ==>  (y2-y1) x + (x1-x2) y + x1 (y1-y2) +y1 (x2-x1) = 0   ==>   Ax+By+C = 0
y2-y1   x2-x1
```

`(A,B)` is the vector defining the perpendicular to the direction of the line. This can be easily seen if you draw the components `A=(y2-y1), B=-(x2-x1)`.

Let's calculate its *unitary* values:

 `U = A / sqrt(A^2 + B^2)`, `V = B / sqrt(A^2 + B^2)`

Notice the other perpendicular vector is `(-A, -B)` or `(-U,-V)`.

Adding 'h' times this perpendidular vector to P2 you get P4:

`P4x= P2x + h U`

`P4y= P2y + h V`

Comment: Small correction - `(A,B)` or normalized `(U,V)` is **not** direction vector of line with equation`Ax+By+C = 0` - it is **normal** vector already (consider line `(0,0)-(1,1)  with equation `x-y=0`)

Comment: @MBo "*Small correction*" No. Big mistake on my own. Lately I'm losing my mind, Thanks for the correction. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

parallel lines have the same or negative direction so:

```
(P4-P3) = c*(P1-P2)
```

where `c` is any scalar constant as the magnitudes of directions may be proportional. For starters we can assume `c=1`

```
P4' = P3 + (P1-P2)
```

now to place `P4` directly under/above `P2` simply change the magnitude of `(P1-P2)` exploiting dot product

```
P4 = P3 + (P1-P2)*dot(P1-P2,P2-P3) / (|P1-P2|*|P2-P3|)
```

[image: overview]

to make this work `P1,P2,P3` must form a triangle and `P2,P3` must not be above/under each other (in case the triangle is right angle) ...

This approach works for 2D and higher dimensionality (not just  2D).

Comment: I think you mean `P4 = P3 + (P1-P2)*dot(P1-P2,P2-P3) / |P1-P2|^2` unless you first normalize vector (P1, P2).

Comment: @Ripi2 ooow yeah yore right I forgot to normalize ... then your solution is the same as mine .... but it should be   /(|P1-P2|*|P2-P3)|